# Disks aren't showing in /dev/sdX

Tags: linux-mint, mount, disk, ssd

I got a 2nd SSD installed in my system, and for some reason it's not showing up in `/dev/sdX` nor is it being shown as a mountable drive. The partitions and the disk exist, but for some reason Linux Mint isn't showing me them when I run `fdisk`, `parted` or even in the GUI frontend for `gparted`. I know for a fact that this SSD still works, it even shows up in the Live USB, and it's got 2 partitions on it, first partition is Ext4 and the other is NTFS which has Windows 10 on it.

Comment: Does `dmesg` show anything useful?

Comment: What program shows the disk and the partitions then? Do they show up in `/proc/partititions`? Is it a SATA drive or an NVMe drive or such?

Comment: @pfnuesel `dmesg` isn't showing me anything relating to what may be wrong. it's only showing me my main SSD, and external storage devices, but not the other SSD.

Comment: @ilkkachu It's not showing up in `/proc/partitions` No program seems to show them anywhere, as far as they're concerned they don't even exist, when it's plugged in and powered on. It's a SATA III SSD by Curcial with capacity of 525Gb, in a ODD Caddy which operates at 3Gbp/s.

Comment: Is the drive detected when you unplug the main drive and start a rescue system? What about using a `GParted` live CD/drive?

Comment: Just add the whole output of `dmesg | grep "] sd\|] ata\|] scsi\|] ahci"` I presume it does show up in BIOS/UEFI and it shows up in lsblk from the live cd?

Comment: What shows `lsblk`?

Comment: @jdwolf it shows all my other drives, but not my other drives with the 2 partitions, and no mount errors shown either.

Comment: @Thomas Shows all my other drives, but not the other ones showing up that it thinks is non-existent.

Comment: Add the output please.